# Dynamic spring tension

Tags: statics, dynamics, springs

I have rope on a spool that is on a cart that is powered and moving at a constant velocity of 0.5 m/s. The end of the rope is passed thru a break and fixed to the wall. one break has a compression spring with an unknown force to create friction to maintain a constant tension on the rope. The spool has a friction of .1 and is .5 m in diameter.

I want to calculate the force the spring needs to put on to maintain a constant tension as a result of the movement of the cart but do not know where to start

[image]

Comment: I have edited the post, can you please take it off hold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not specified the diameter of the spool nor the friction constant. Neither have you specified the friction constant in the pulleys. I’m guessing you’re trying to find the required spring force in the pulleys so that an appropriate force is subtracted from 38 N such that the remaining force cancels out the rotation friction in the spool.

Edit:
I am unable to comment so I will write here. You want to calculate the required spring force to maintain a constant tension in the rope. However, since the rope is fixed to a wall it cannot move between the pulleys and therefore the tension results purely from radius, friction and moment of inertia (if there is angular acceleration) of the spool. The friction in the spool causes a moment $M_{friction}$ (opposing uncoiling of the spool). This is balanced by tension in the rope so

$ M_{total} = M_{friction}+M_{inertia} = Tr \:\: => \:\:T=\frac{M_{total}}{r}$

Therefore, if you wish to maintain a constant tension in the rope, you must maintain a constant $\frac{M}{r}$.

Comment: "passed thru 2 pulleys and fixed to the wall" makes it look like the 38N is not the driving force?

Comment: Yes, I agree. As I understood it, the cart is moving at constant 0.5 m/s and 38 N is what results. However, the more I look at this the less it makes sense. Why pulleys if the rope is fixed to a wall and the pulleys cannot rotate?

Answer (score 2):

The constraints set out in your question don't make sense. You have described an object which is moving at a constant velocity - this means that there must be no resultant force on it. As illustrated, the tension in the rope would be slowing the cart down, unless there is some driving force inside the cart which you have not illustrated.

My best guess here is that the cart is powered, and you're asking what the force should be on the roller to keep the tension at the wall anchor at 38N?

The problem is, you've set this out as a 'physics type' problem, with 2D weightless string, constant velocities etc. whereas the resistive force generated by squashing a 3D rope between some rollers is an 'engineering type' problem, which is best answered by physical testing, as the force required will vary over the lifetime of the system as the rope and rollers wear...

I hope the above goes some way to helping you out - feel free to edit your question to provide more specific details if you can.